# Laravel Show PDF encoding error

Tags: laravel, pdf, encoding

I am trying to show pdf file using laravel

I use this code for this

```
 $file='C:\Users\imediasun\Downloads/Startseite.pdf';
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   , 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64',

        );
        return  response()->file($file, $headers);
```

But I receive this encoding errors
http://prntscr.com/j6laf4

What I need to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        $file='C:\Users\imediasun\Downloads/Startseite.pdf';
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'base64'

        ];
        return  response()->file($file, $headers);
```

Let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `file` is on the `ResponseFactory` interface.

```
return Response::make($file, 200)
    ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
    ->header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=\"{$filename}\"");
```

As an aside, I'm not sure you want a a local path in your code. But you're probably just testing. You could also  `resource_path('path/to/your/file.pdf')`